# Allow iptables communication only between two clients (mac-addresses)

Tags: iptables

I have a network with two vlans (vlan 7 and vlan 8). i want to block any communication between this two networks except some client mac addresses.
I want to allow one client in vlan 7 to communicate with another specific client in the other vlan 8.

I hope there is any possibility to allow the communication from one mac address in vlan 7 to another mac address in vlan 8 but the client from vlan 7 can't communicate with any other client in vlan 8 except the one i allow.

Server1 IP-Address: 172.16.7.1 in VLAN 7 (DHCP 172.16.7.*)

Server2 IP-Address: 172.16.7.2 in VLAN 7 (NO DHCP)

Server2 IP-Address: 172.16.8.1 in VLAN 8 (DHCP 172.16.8.*)

I want to isolade all clients between this two vlans except the client communication i allow.

I can upload a diagram if its unclear.

The vlan 7 is a guest vlan with client isolation, (ruckus, unifi, juniper ...) with guest policies and it doesn't matter if the clients in vlan 8 see others in its network. i only want to allow a specific from 7 to 8 why should mac spoofing be a problem? And i don't want to create a high secured network between this two i want to allow temporary connections between 2 clients in 2 different networks (vlans).

(Little explanation)
You have a smartphone in a client isolated wifi network (VLAN7), you share this network with others.
And a bunch of network musik players, tvs and printers in (VLAN8) and you want to allow only your smartphone (VLAN7) to communicate with one of the devices from vlan 8 not all tvs not all musik players only one specific device.

Comment: These two vlans have to dhcp servers the first creates a gateway with 172.16.7.* in vlan 7 and its only connected to this network with ip-address 172.16.7.1.               The second server creates dhcp with 172.16.8.* with ip-address 172.16.8.1 and its connected to both networks the one from the first server in vlan 7 and vlan 8. I hope i can use iptables to handle communications from clients between this 2 networks (vlans) with the second server.

Comment: iptables, as its name implies, is designed to work at IP level (and the layer above: tcp etc.), with some features for other layers. I now realize that this is more difficult than it appears because iptables currently can only filter based on source mac address on incoming interface (nothing on outgoing interface). While dual way communication is easy to restrict, preventing one-way communication (to non allowed peers) appears much harder to achieve. That doesn't mean it's not possible, just it doesn't look easy.

Comment: The easiest method is to have DHCP servers handle fixed IP addresses to special clients and  have iptables now handle known IPs. You can think a bad client can spoof an IP, but it can also spoof a MAC address anyway. Can't you do this?